# Nginx optimizing image for reverse image proxy

Tags: optimization, nginx, proxy, pagespeed

I have setup an image reverse proxy for my Nginx and it works. However, I would like to serve an optimized version of the image.

The original URL (being proxied) actually contains query parameters without image extensions such as `http://external.server.com/asp/service?k1=v1&k2=v2`. I tried trick Cloudflare or pagespeed to treat it as an image and hope one of which could optimize the image. So my new proxied URL is now `http://mydomain.com/some/path/image.png?k1=v1&k2=v2`. (Config below)

However, it didn't seem to work. Both CF and pagespeed seems to only optimize referenced static images from the serving html, but not ones that are dynamically requested with any url. Is this true? How could I setup so I am able to provide a reverse image proxy to serve optimized images with Nginx? Thanks a million.

```
server {
    listen 8080;
    proxy_cache CACHE;
    pagespeed on;

    location /some/path/image.png {
      proxy_pass http://external.server.com/asp/service;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't answer for how CloudFlare works, but `mod_pagespeed` can optimize images in two different ways:

1. Rewrite image URLs found in HTML or CSS statically on a page. In this case the URL itself will be rewritten to something like `ximage.png,qk1-v1&k2=v2.pagespeed.ic.Hash.png`. And that URL will be served optimized.
2. [`InPlaceResourceOptimization`](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/system#ipro), where the image is rewritten and served from the original URL. As you can see from the documentation, this feature is only available for the Apache-version of `mod_pagespeed`. We are working on porting it to the the Nginx versions.

In general, the first method is more effective, are these URLs not found statically in HTML? Are they dynamically generated in JS?

Comment: These URLs are called by JS to serve as image map tiles, so it looks like the second option is more applicable, however, it is for Apache :(. Do you have a link to any related porting project that can be used? Maybe one work around for me now is to generate a static HTML that span all the image tiles so page speed can pre-optimize them? Or, does pagespeed optimize images found in dynamically generated HTML. (So I can fetch the html including the URL to be optimized first, then fetch the optimized image?)

Comment: Oh, it looks like Nginx supports In-place Resource Optimization now! https://github.com/pagespeed/ngx_pagespeed/issues/42

Comment: Somehow I am able to optimize empty (all transparent) png file, but not the ones with some content. Checking the statistics, it says drop intentionally, but not sure why it is dropped.

Comment: I eventually figured out what happened. The latest ngx_pagespeed already includes InPlaceResourceOptimization. So I added "pagespeed ModPagespeedInPlaceResourceOptimization on;" and now it works! Thanks